# What statistical test can compare frequencies of men among control and treatment groups?

Tags: contingency-tables, frequency

Supposing I have two groups of people: `Control` and `Treatment`, in which the control group consists 30000 observations, whereas the treatment has 7000.

Does it makes sense to compare if the frequency of men is significantly different on controls and treatment groups using a `t-test`? I do not know if this makes sense since these are binary variables.

What test should I use? Is there a package that does that using `R`?

Comment: The "R package" request is strictly speaking off-topic here - see our [help/on-topic] - but the statistical content of this question is fine, though it could quite possibly be closed as a duplicate of an existing thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably stay away from a t-test on this one unless you are certain that a normal approximation makes sense for the frequencies in your data.

It sounds like you actually have a 2x2 contingency table. You may want to consider [Fisher's Exact Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test).

Yes this is implemented in various places in R. For example in the [*stats* package](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/fisher.test.html).

As should always be stated when using null-hypothesis testing. Make sure that the assumptions underlying the test make sense for your data. An easy to understand write-up of some of some of the assumptions behind this test can be found [here](http://www.statisticssolutions.com/fisher-exact-test/).

Comment: i have read here (http://www.cookbook-r.com/Statistical_analysis/Frequency_tests/) to use a Chi-Square test to compare groups. is it ok?

Comment: Chi-Squared relies on asymptotics and is probably a fine choice if your cell counts (i.e., if the count in each of the 4 cells of your 2x2 contingency table) are large. If you have any small cell counts then you probably want to deal with the exact calculation given by Fisher's Exact test.